# How does Lightroom associate a preset with a camera profile?

Tags: lightroom, presets, camera-profiles

How does Lightroom associate a preset with a camera profile?  Is this the UUID in the preset's .xmp file?  If so, how/where is this associated with the .dcp file?

The underlying issue I'm trying to address is taking some of my existing *camera-specific* presets that I've purchased, and making my own tweaks to them for different camera systems that I own.  I understand how the edit the dcp files; I just can't figure out where the connection between the xmp and dcp file is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

The `.dcp` association is unrelated to the UUID of the preset, and it's actually unrelated to the preset `.xmp` whatsoever. All that the Lightroom preset specifies is the `ProfileName` property of the `.dcp` file (note that this is **not** the filename). When you apply the preset to a photo, Lightroom goes and searches your camera profile directory for a profile with a matching `ProfileName` property and a compatible `UniqueCameraModelRestriction` property. If one is found, you'll see that the calibration profile changes. If not, I believe that the calibration profile metadata will still be updated for the photo, but Lightroom will continue to use the camera default profile for that photo, since the requested profile isn't available.

P.S. For anyone else trying to do this, editing the `.dcp` file is the hard part, and the only good way that I know of to do it is to use [dcpTool](http://dcptool.sourceforge.net/Introduction.html)